# Oracle prefix data to a clob

Tags: oracle, procedure, clob

I have a procedure (see test case below), which works fine that appends data to a CLOB. In addition to appending the data in the CLOB I'm encapsulating the VALUE of SYSDATE in tags so I can keep track of when the data was updated in the CLOB.

Though I'm only showing data with 10-20 characters in my example the CLOB can be extremely big and in many cases concatenated within a block before being placed into the CLOB.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';

CREATE table t(
seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
c CLOB DEFAULT ' ',
create_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
);
/


insert into t (c) values (' ')
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE lob_append(
  p_clob IN OUT CLOB,
  p_text IN     VARCHAR2
)
AS
  l_text varchar2(32760);
  l_date_string VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN

select '[' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MMDDYYYY-HH24:MI:SS') || ']'
    into l_date_string  from dual;

 
-- newline each time code is appended for clarity.
  l_text :=chr(10) || l_date_string || chr(10)
            || p_text || chr(10)
            || l_date_string||chr(10);

  dbms_lob.writeappend(p_clob, length(l_text), l_text );
END;
/

DECLARE
  l_clob CLOB := empty_clob();
BEGIN
  SELECT c INTO l_clob FROM t WHERE seq_num = 1 FOR UPDATE;

 lob_append(l_clob, rpad('Z',20,'Z'));


l_clob  := empty_clob();
SELECT c INTO l_clob FROM t WHERE seq_num = 1 FOR UPDATE;


lob_append(l_clob, rpad('Y',10,'Y'));


END;
/
```

I'm looking to do something like this but by calling a procedure similar to the one posted above.

```
UPDATE T
   SET C = RPAD('A',20,'A') || CHR(10) || C 
 WHERE SEQ_NUM = 1
/
```

I  welcome any and all helpful suggestions and or design changes since this hasn't been implemented yet. Thanks in advance to all who answer.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If you need to wrap an update of a value of some column in some row, you need a function, not a procedure.

Comment: @asyentx I'm looking to provide an interface to an application that prefixes new data of a CLOB instead of appending. I posted the update statement as an example of what the result I'm looking for should be.

Comment: Then you may use trigger. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0896089432ef588b5657e903d79cdb71)

Comment: @astentx while I appreciate your effort this doesn't solve my issue. I have some applications, which may want to append. My original example did that. I have other applications that may want to prefix the data where the newest appears at the beginning of the CLOB. For example, your medical chart at a DR. When they open it they want to see the notes from your last visit appear first

Comment: Now it became clearer and look like you designing in a wrong way. RDBMS is not a good document store, instead you may add datetime column and place the date here keeping clob value as is. Then format the output at your app side during display.